# How to create a translucent layer on click of button, which would slide up for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Hi I want to create a layer of the type in the image below.

[image]

The layer (with Capture mode and Shutter speed) slides up when I click on the setting button.

I am unable to figure out what should I do do create something like this. Also want to have the similar translucency in the layer as well as in the buttons on it also.

On click on the same button again, the layer(with Capture mode and Shutter speed) disappears, leaving what was there on the screen before (the camera view and the lower bar with the camera capture button, and the two setting buttons)

Please any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a UIView and place every button you need there, and place it below the screen size. then when you click the setting button you call core animation to move the view up, click setting again to move it down.